# limiting cropped picture aspect ratio with jcrop or it's alternatives

Tags: javascript, image-processing, crop, jcrop

i am using jcrop to crop pictures on my websites. user can have any aspect ratio of the picture. is there any js library (or way to do it with jcrop) which would allow to limit aspect ratio so that user wouldn't be able to choose f.ex. too thin picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just realised that limiting aspect ratios while selecting the wanted area can be very confusing for the user, so i decided to check the coordinates of selected area before it gets submitted and warn user if picture is too thin

Answer (score 1):

As [documentation](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html) say you can limit width and height of cropped picture with option minSize. Just set minSize to for example [20,20] so to prohibit selecting pictures thinner then 20 pixels.

Also you can limit user with fixed aspect ratio with option aspectRatio.

Comment: yes, but user will still be able to select f.ex. a picture 500px to 20px which is aspect ratio 25 to 1. what i wanted was prohibiting user to select the area which would be f.ex. thinner than 2 to 1 ratio, while still alowing it to be flexible. f.ex. 19px to 10px should still be ok.